# How do i create a simple page that displays information from my visual basic programs variables

Tags: vb.net, printing, ms-word

I have created a program that takes a users input of a bunch of fields. Now what i want to do is create a word document using the information that was entered so users can print a page with the information and save it as well. sorry if this is not the place to ask. just thought it was worth a try at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this,

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316383

http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/VB/0440__Windows/CreateWorddocumentandprint.htm